# Bind this in an instance

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2017

I've a simple class handling the readable stream of a Fetch response:

```
class ProgressIndicator {

  constructor(res) {

    this.res = res;

    this.contentLength = parseInt(res.headers.get('content-length', 10));

    this.loaded = 0;

    return new Response(

      new ReadableStream({

        start(controller) {

          console.log(this);

          this.reader = this.res.body.getReader();

          this.readStream(controller);

        }

      })

    );

  }
```

Obviously if I log this inside the start function, I get the own function.

Any idea of how I can bind the ProgressIndicator object to the start function?

Comment: create attribute within ProgressIndicator self = this; and log (self); will refer to class scope

Comment: @Sameer I've used self and it works, but it's not dangerous if I create more than one instances? Or it creates a new self for each instance?

Comment: It will create new instance for each. Unless you declare self as Static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create attribute within ProgressIndicator class, it will refer to class scope.

```
 class ProgressIndicator {

  var selfScope = this;

  constructor(res) {

    this.res = res;

    this.contentLength = parseInt(res.headers.get('content-length', 10));

    this.loaded = 0;

    return new Response(

      new ReadableStream({

        start(controller) {

          console.log(selfScope);

          this.reader = this.res.body.getReader();

          this.readStream(controller);

        }

      })

    );

  }
```

Comment: create attribute within ProgressIndicator self = this; and log (self); will refer to class scope

Answer (score 0):

an alternate solution could be to define start as an arrow function because [arrow functions don't have their own binding to 'this'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
class ProgressIndicator {
  constructor(res) {
    this.res = res;
    this.contentLength = parseInt(res.headers.get('content-length', 10));
    this.loaded = 0;
    return new Response(
      new ReadableStream({
        start: (controller)=>{
          console.log(this);
          this.reader = this.res.body.getReader();
          this.readStream(controller);
        }
      })
    );
  }
```